# SAS - append string macro variable to data set name

Tags: sas

I'm trying to append a string macro variable to a data set name in SAS. I want to create datasets that read something like work.cps2020jan and work.cps2020feb. But that's not what I am getting. My code:

```
%macro loop(values); 
 
     %let count=%sysfunc(countw(&values));

     %do i = 1 %to &count;                                           
      %let value=%qscan(&values,&i,%str(,));                                                                                          
      %put &value; 

    data work.cps2020&value.;
        set "A:\cpsb2020&value" ;

    mth = "&value.";

    keep
    PEMLR 
    mth
    ;

    run;

    %end;                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                              
%mend;
                         
%loop(%str(jan,feb));
```

Running this code results in the following output in the log:

```
NOTE: There were 138697 observations read from the data set
      A:\cpsb2020jan.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CPS2020 has 138697 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: The data set WORK.JAN has 138697 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           4.29 seconds
      cpu time            0.20 seconds


feb

NOTE: There were 139248 observations read from the data set
      A:\cpsb2020feb.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CPS2020 has 139248 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: The data set WORK.FEB has 139248 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           4.44 seconds
      cpu time            0.15 seconds
```

I don't understand why my macro creates two datasets per loop instead of one dataset per loop called work.cps2020jan and work.cps2020feb. If I change &value. to &i. SAS outputs work.cps20201 and work.cps20202. But that's not what I want.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%QSCAN` macro function will mask it's result with special invisible (non-printable) characters only visible to the macro processor system.

What happened is that

```
data work.cps2020&value.;
```

was seen as

```
data work.cps2020<mask-character><non-masked part of symbol value><mask-character>;
```

during executor processing, which treated the non-printable mask character as a non-syntax token separator, resulting in a `DATA` statement listing two output tables.

```
data work.cps2020 jan;
```

The positions of mask characters in a macro variable can be observed (in the LOG) using `%put _user_`, or, the actual symbol contents can be captured from a metadata view such as `SASHELP.VMACRO` or `DICTIONARY.MACRO`

Let's simplify your macro and add some logging and symbol capture

```
%macro loop(values); 
  %local count i;

  %let count=%sysfunc(countw(&values));
  %do i = 1 %to &count;
    %let value=%qscan(&values,&i,%str(,));

    %put _user_;                   %*--- log them masks;

    data x&i;                      %* --- symbol capture;
      set sashelp.vmacro;
      where name like '%VALUE%';
      value_hex = put (value,$HEX40.);
    run;

    %* --- do the step that creates two tables;

    data work.cps2020&value.;
      set sashelp.class;
    run;
  %end;
%mend;

options nomprint nosymbolgen nomlogic;

%loop(%str(jan,feb));

proc print data=x1 noobs style(data)=[fontsize=14pt fontfamily="Courier"];
  var value:;
run;
```

LOG snippet, those little boxes are the special invisible masking characters (I am showing them in image captures because stack overflow / html won't show non-printable characters)

[image]

Same LOG text, copy and pasted into *Notepad2* show the mask characters as *control characters*

[image]

The `Proc PRINT` of the captured macro symbol data will expose the hexadecimal masking characters

[image]

- `06` macro %quote start
- `08` macro %quote end
- `01` macro %str start
- `02` macro %str end
- `1E` masked version of comma

Comment: Excellent explanation

Comment: Wow - that was great, thanks! After replacing qscan() with scan() the macro did what I wanted it to do (loop through the list of strings and append the string to the dataset name).

Answer (score 0):

`&value` is returned as quoted by `%qscan()`. Use `%scan()` instead. Quoted macro variables can sometimes cause issues on resolution when they're used in this way. It's best to only quote them when needed, such as in a `%put` statement that has a % sign within it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `%qscan()`. If the value contained any characters that need macro quoting then they would be invalid for use in a member name anyway. So use `%scan()` instead.

But when used inside of a macro the tokenizer will sometimes mistakenly see things like `xxx&mvar` as two tokens even when there are no special characters in `&mvar`.  You can group the value you are generating to work around that.

For example by making a new macro variable

```
%let dsn=cps2020&value.;
data work.&dsn. ;
```

Or use the `%unquote()` function:

```
data %unquote(work.cps2020&value.);
```

Or use a name literal:

```
data work."cps2020&value."n;
```